# AngularJS add empty JSON to http request

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I´m trying to fetch data via http-GET request in an angularJS service from a REST Web Service. The point is that the `REST-SERVICE` needs an empty JSON object {} to work.

Here is the method in my service:

```
srv.getTriggerStatus = function(sessionID) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "samplepath?sessionId="+sessionID, //samplepath = localhost rest path
        });
        return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
    };
```

So I tried different things like add
`data:{}` or `parameters:{}` to my `$http-request` but nothing seems to work.

**So how can I add an empty JSON Object to the http request ?**

Comment: The GET requests doesn't have a body, so it's in the URI that you give parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to send some query / request params to REST-SERVICE ?

Comment: @Siva The only parameter is the sessionId but the empty JSON is required.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant If I change my request to POST how can I submit the empty JSON ?

Comment: With GET you can send JSON object. Try POST instead

Comment: Try method: 'POST', data: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try POST request and pass the empty JSON using data property.

```
srv.getTriggerStatus = function(sessionID) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            url: "samplepath?sessionId="+sessionID, //samplepath = localhost rest path
        });
        return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
    };
```